# Postfix always BCC root@hostname.domain.com

Tags: email, postfix

I'm attempting to setup a postfix relay system for my LAN. A lot of my services are blocked from WAN access and I want to be able to get notifications from them.

As it stands it currently "works" but each e-mail is accompanied by a "Mailer Deamon Undeliverable" e-mail because it's sending correctly but always trying to BCC: `root@hostname.domain.com` which doesn't resolve. I only use @domain.com for e-mail.

Here is my config for a "guest" VM (sends via the `relayhost`), I've tried a bunch but am out of ideas any help is appreciated.

I wonder If I can fix this somehow in the `relayhost` vs the guests?

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
biff = no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
append_dot_mydomain = no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
readme_directory = no                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem                                                                                                                                                                                                              
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key                                                                                                                                                                                                             
smtpd_use_tls=yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache                                                                                                                                                                                               
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache                                                                                                                                                                                                 
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination                                                                                                                                                                       
myhostname = domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
myorigin = domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
mydestination = domain.com, localhost                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
relayhost = smtp.domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128                                                                                                                                                                                                             
mailbox_size_limit = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
recipient_delimiter = +                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
inet_interfaces = loopback-only                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
inet_protocols = all                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
masquerade_domains = domain.com  

#THINGS I HAVE TRIED...##
#smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/bad_recipients, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit                                                                                                                         
#transport_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/transport_maps                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


/etc/aliases

postmaster:    root                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
root: user@domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
trash: /tmp/mail.trash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue with `mydestination`. I should not have had `domain.com` in that field. I removed it and set it to `mydestination = hostname hostname.domain.com localhost` and now it works as expected.